# Assigning a value of data for each record having the same condition in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 like:

```
Period    Name     Value
1         A        10
2         A        20
3         A        30
4         A        40
1         B        50          
2         B        80
3         B        70
4         B        60
```

What I need to write a select query includes a new column `MainValue` which contains the value where period=4 for a name for each data.

Example:

```
 Period     Name     Value    MainValue
    1         A        10       40
    2         A        20       40
    3         A        30       40
    4         A        40       40
    1         B        50       60 
    2         B        80       60
    3         B        70       60
    4         B        60       60
```

How can I provide this? I tried the one below, but it is not working as I want.

```
Select 
    *, 
    (select Value where Period = 4) as MainValue 
from myTable;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your subquery has two major problems. First is that it is not a complete query, there is no FROM. Second is that it should be correlated to your main query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Period, Name, Value, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Period=4 THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS MainValue
FROM mytable
```

The query uses a window function with a condition applied over `Name` partitions: the function returns the `Value` corresponding to `Period=4` inside each partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways. A correlated sub-query as the column, a cross apply to a correlated query, or a cte. I personally like the cte approach. It would look something like this.

```
with MainValues as
(
    select Name
        , Value
    from SomeTable
    where Period = 4
)

select st.*
    , mv.Value as MainValue
from SomeTable st
join MainValues mv on st.Name = mv.Name
```